# Use iOS10 Photos Markup feature in own app

Tags: ios, iphone

Is it possible to use the Markup feature from the Photos app/extension in my own app? I'd like to use this exact screen, if possible:

https://www.igeeksblog.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/Use-Markup-in-Photos-App-in-iOS-10-on-iPhone-and-iPad.jpg

As described here:
https://www.igeeksblog.com/how-to-use-markup-in-photos-and-messages-in-ios-10/

Thanks!